# Google maps v3 info window opening outside map viewport

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

If a marker is clicked near the top of the map viewport, the infowindow loads outside the viewable area and the map must be dragged to see infowindow content.

Ideally I don't want the map to auto pan. Is there a way to load the infowindow in a different direction, e.g. if the marker is at the top of the viewport to display the infowindow in a downward direction.

Comment: Are you referring to Google's default info window or a custom info window?

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't open google's default infowindows in a different direction since you don't implement your own infowindow class. But you can disable auto-pannnig simply passing *TRUE* to **disableAutoPan** property of **InfoWindowOptions** object like [documentation said](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions).

Answer (score 6):

There is an example that used to be part of the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 [Code Samples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/), that has moved over to GitHub, named: [SmartInfoWindow](https://github.com/jjok/SmartInfoWindow). It does exactly what you are describing. Check into the underlying code and that should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: The provided links are broken... they must have been removed

Comment: @r0m4n: Thanks for the heads-up. I will take a look at this later today and update the answer to correct the problem, update the links if possible, and add more detail to the answer, so it's not so link-dependent.

Comment: later today in January 2017? ;)

Comment: @RyanVeteze: I made that promise, got busy at work, and it must have flown completely out of my head. But since you gave me a little poke, I (finally) dove in and fixed the busted links. Thanks for the ping - I feel better that I kept my word eventually ~