# Google Maps infowindow is extending outside the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple infowindow, and I have followed Google Javascript tutorial, but the infowindow is starting above the map, outside the window.

I thought I made some mistake, but looking at Google example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple-max), I see the same defect (tried with Safari and Chrome): the InfoWindow is positioned outside the map.

What is wrong in that sample page?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881502/google-maps-v3-info-window-opening-outside-map-viewport

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by enclosing the infowindow content into a div with max-height:

```
content ="<div style='max-height: 400px !important;'>"+contentstring+ "<div>";
infoWin.setContent(content);
infoWin.open(map, marker);
```